# Can't rotate any mesh

Tags: objects

All of a sudden I cannot rotate ANY mesh on any axis
Until today I was able to rotate any mesh on any axis (usi9ng the mouse to drag).
None of the rotations have been locked - see image below.
What have I done to cause this?

[image]

I have uploaded a project created using the original meshes which I removed and added a mesh cube which won't rotate.

[image]

Comment: Will the default cube on the new file work?

Comment: If I start a new 'project' a mesh cube WILL rotate.   If I add a mesh cube to the existing project it WON'T rotate.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn on any settings under options at the top right of the 3D viewport?

Comment: Maybe. But not intentionally.  Exactly where are these settings?

Comment: The only thing I can see in your screenshot is that you've set the _Rotation_ from the default _XYZ Euler_ to _Quaternion (WXYZ)_, but that would still let you rotate objects... actually the selected object shows a rotation of 0.995 on W and 0.1 on Z. Could you save the file a second time, throw everything out except for a default cube that's not rotating and upload it here? If nothing works it is not necessary to upload the complete model, I guess.

Comment: Oh wait - you're dragging with the mouse on the axis value to rotate? If you did that on the first one, W, it will not show any rotation in the viewport.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and everyone  else.  I have now uploaded a blender file containing only a mesh cube which won't rotate using the original 'project' with all of my ship removed.   AND I noticed that somehow I had selected (turned on) Options/ Transform/ Locations so now I have it working.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a possibility that you have somehow accidentally turned on one of the following options:

Transform Affect Only Origins/Locations

Turning on either one will stop you from normally rotating the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  YES that is the answer/solution.  I have no idea how I could have accidentally set Locations.

Comment: @JohnArnold Haha, no worries, I've done the exact same thing in the past. Glad I could help